# To git checkout without overwriting data

Tags: git, git-merge, git-checkout

**How can you `git-checkout` without overwriting the data?**

I run

```
git checkout master
```

I get

```
error: Entry 'forms/answer.php' would be overwritten by merge. Cannot merge.
```

This is surprising, since I did not know that Git merges when I `git-checkout`.
I have always run after the command separately `git merge new-feature`.
This seems to be apparently unnecessary if Git merges at checkout.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Git is warning you that forms/answers.php has changes in your working copy or index that have not been committed.

You can use **[git-stash](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash)** to save your changes then **git-stash apply** to restore them.

The common use case of **git-stash** is that you are working on changes but then must temporarily checkout a different branch to make a bug fix.  So you can *stash* your changes in your index and working copy, checkout the other branch, make the bug fix, commit, checkout the original branch, and **git-stash apply** to restore your changes and pick-up where you left off.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning `git-stash`! - I did not know that its purpose is to be used in the situations like this one.

Comment: For whatever reason, I couldn't use the git-stash command. Instead, I had to use "git stash" (no hyphen).

Comment: If all you want is to inspect a different revision while keeping your uncommitted changes (which is sometimes the case when looking for the revision introducing a bug), Jakub's suggestion (`git checkout -m`) is much easier.

Answer (score 19):

Git does a 2-way merge of *uncomitted changes* when switching branches (using `git checkout <branch>`), but ordinarily it does only trivial (tree-level) merge.

Besides `git-stash` [solution by Karl Voigtland](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291459/to-git-checkout-without-overwriting-data/1291470#1291470), you can give additional options to [git checkout](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout), choosing one of the following options:

- Tell git to **try harder to merge** uncomitted changes into branch you switch to with `-m` / `--merge` option. With this option, a three-way merge between the current branch, your working tree contents, and the new branch is done, and you will be on the new branch.
- Tell git to **overwrite** uncomitted changes, throwing away local changes with `-f` option.  Warning: uncomitted changes will be lost!

Comment: Thanks for this.  The second one (`git checkout -f master`) helped me get back.  I don't know what changes I lost, but they weren't important as this is a very old copy of a repo which I just wanted to inspect.

Comment: Is it possible to do the "opposite" of `git checkout -f`? Basically I'd like Git to give up checking out the files that would cause conflict.

Answer (score 4):

You can do a `git reset --soft` to make your `HEAD` point to the new branch, but leave all the files as they are (including the ones that were changed in the new branch). Then you can use `git checkout` to checkout just the files that you really want from the new branch.

```
       git reset [<mode>] [<commit>]
           This form resets the current branch head to <commit> and possibly updates the index (resetting it to the
           tree of <commit>) and the working tree depending on <mode>. If <mode> is omitted, defaults to --mixed.
           The <mode> must be one of the following:

           --soft
               Does not touch the index file or the working tree at all (but resets the head to <commit>, just like
               all modes do). This leaves all your changed files "Changes to be committed", as git status would put
               it.
```

Answer (score 0):

Jakub has also mentioned `git checkout --merge`, but at the time of writing, **I disrecommend this option.** In my case, it failed with an "error: Dirty index: cannot merge" and destroyed my entire working copy, without backing it up in any stash or something like this. Don't use it, rather use a traditional stash instead.