# Called git checkout -b branchname on pre-existing branch; was old one overwritten?

Tags: git, command-line

I've cloned a large, well-maintained repository. By accident I used the `-b` flag when checking out a different branch.  Git says "Switched to a new branch". Was the pre-existing branch overwritten, is git's output misleading, or did I make another mistake?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Was the preexisting branch overwrote,

No.
The [default branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485578/how-do-i-change-a-git-remote-head-to-point-to-something-besides-master) has been checked out, and a new local branch has been created from its HEAD.

You can see all the branches with:

```
git branch -a
```

Simply switch back to the upstream branch of your choice with

```
git checkout -b aBranch --track origin/aBranch
# if the local branch was already there
git checkout -B aBranch --track origin/aBranch
```

Note that if you have work in progress, you need first to go a `git stash`, as explained in "[To `git checkout` without overwriting data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1291470/6309)".

Comment: Thanks, you're getting me closer.  I get this output (should I just choose a different branch name?): git checkout -b client_release_6.12 --track remotes/origin/client_release_6.12
fatal: A branch named 'client_release_6.12' already exists.

Comment: @mda: if you already have a *local* branch `client_release_6.12`, then the error message is normal. The question is: does this branch start from `origin/client_release_6.12`. You can reset it by typing `git checkout -B client_release_6.12 --track origin/client_release_6.12` (note the `-B` instead of `-b`)

Comment: I cloned the remote repository as usual git clone URL, then possibly created a new local branch of the same name as a remote branch...not sure from git's output.

Comment: @mda ok, but if the remote repo has a branch named `client_release_6.12`, then it is best forcing the start of the local `client_release_6.12` branch to `origin/client_release_6.12` (the branch from the upstream repo).

Comment: OK, that worked, but I had to do "git stash" first.  So the commands are: git stash; git checkout -B client_release_6.12 remote/origin/client_release_6.12

Comment: If my comment above sounds right, please edit your answer and I'll give it the check-mark :-)

Comment: @mda your comment sounds right, and I have added a link to another SO question, which illustrates it.